# Call SCSS map from another file

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a SCSS map in a file called '_colors.scss' which I want to call it from another file called 'app.scss'. I have tried some methods but I can´t find the right way.

This is my '_colors.scss' file:

```scss
/*    Functions    */

@function color($elem, $variant) {
  @return map-get(map-get($color, $elem), $variant);
}

/*    Variables   */

$colors: (
  text: (
    1: #162c5b,
    2: #565678,
    3: #ababc9,
    soft: #718097,
    footer: #ff2a91,
    1i: #fff,
  ),
  bg: (
    hero: #038aff,
    awards: purple,
    features: #5ccaa7,
    tools: #febd3d,
    3: #d2daf0,
    infinite: #161348,
    footer: #161348,
    line-footer: #2f2c5b,
    pink: #f1ecfd,
    white: #fff,
  ),
);
```

And this is my 'app.scss' file where I want to call it from, but it does not seem to call the map, so I can use it in my scss file, like I am doing with the background color of the '.box' class. What am I missing?

```scss
@use 'colors' as cl;


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
}

.hero {
  width: 100%;
  .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 90px 0;
    width: min(1200px, 100%);
    .box {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      padding: 28px;
      background-color: color(bg, hero);
      h2 {
        font-size: 2rem;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        font-weight: 800;
      }
      p {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: color(text, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't simple @use work for your case? "@use as" lets use @include for mixings with a namespace. like namespace.mixingname

```
@use 'colors';
```

or

```
@import 'colors';
```

Comment: Hello Volkan, yes!, it worked with @import. BTW, do you know what is '@each' for in SCSS?

Comment: @LuisAlejandroLopezdeAnda That's a question you should turn to the documentation for instead of asking on StackOverflow. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Ok, well Sean, but Stackoverflow is a community platform, It is like asking a friend. Of course, I would have to search if I don´t get an answer.